# Trying to change the geometry loader in the template from TDS to gltf

Tags: javascript, three.js

Trying to change the geometry loader in the template from TDS to gltf.
This way its work perfectly with tds loader.

```
  ` this.resources.searchImage = new Image()
    this.resources.searchImage.addEventListener('load', () =>
    {
        this.resources.areaImage = new Image()
        this.resources.areaImage.addEventListener('load', () =>
        {
            this.tdsLoader.load('suzanne.3ds', (_suzanne) =>
            {
                this.resources.suzanne = _suzanne.children[0]

                // Set environment
                this.setEnvironment()

                // Set debug
                this.setDebug()
```

but when im trying to change it does not working

```
        this.resources.searchImage.addEventListener('load', () =>
        {
            this.resources.areaImage = new Image()
            this.resources.areaImage.addEventListener('load', () =>
            {
                this.gltfLoader.load('switch.gltf', (_switch) =>
                {
                    this.resources.switch = _switch.children[0]
                    // Set environment
                    this.setEnvironment()

                    // Set debug
                    this.setDebug()
                })
            })
```